# How to handle uncaughtErrorEvent & Exception to write a log in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

```
var application = require("application");

application.on(application.uncaughtErrorEvent, function (args) {
    if (args.android) {
        // For Android applications, args.android is an NativeScriptError.
        console.log("NativeScriptError: " + args.android);
    } else if (args.ios) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios is NativeScriptError.
        console.log("NativeScriptError: " + args.ios);
    }
});
```

I tried above example in {N}@2.0.1 but it does not work for me.

Can you explain more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in NativeScript github repository [enter link description here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2309) as follows:

application.uncaughtErrorEvent will trigger whenever your app is crashing and the cause is not handled.

For example:
if you try to initialize an android button with null context like this in your main-page.js it will throw an error

in main-page.js

```
var btn = new android.widget.Button(null);
What you can do to catch this error is to use uncaughtErrorEvent

in app.js

"use strict";
var application = require("application");

application.on(application.uncaughtErrorEvent, function (args) {
    if (args.android) {
        // For Android applications, args.android is an NativeScriptError.
        console.log(" *** NativeScriptError *** : " + args.android);
        console.log(" *** StackTrace *** : " + args.android.stackTrace);
        console.log(" *** nativeException *** : " + args.android.nativeException);
    }
    else if (args.ios) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios is NativeScriptError.
        console.log("NativeScriptError: " + args.ios);
    }
});
application.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });
```

From the log you can see the following information:

```
NativeScriptError : Error: The application crashed because of an uncaught exception.
```

from the stackTrace you can see the cause of this error :

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources 
 android.content.Context.getResources()' on null reference object
```

You also have a pointer where the error has occured:

```
Frame: function:'navigatingTo', `file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.cameraUpload/files/app/main-page.js',
```

line: 11, column: 15`

Comment: Hi Nick. From my testing - this will still show the crash screen. Is there any way to not show the error screen and ignore it?